# Repository for Oracle Coherence Maven plugin

Tags: oracle, maven, caching

does anybody know which is the maven repository where the plugin "[maven-gar-plugin][1]" is stored?

Thank you very much!

Antonio

**References** : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/coherence_project.htm#MAVEN8910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a full install of Coherence will install the desired plug-ins into your maven repository.   However if you'd like to get them directly using maven, you can now do so by using the Oracle Maven Repository at: maven.oracle.com

You'll have to register for this repository (free of course), but once you've done that you can get the latest releases from there.

Hope this helps.

-- Brian

Comment: It installs the pom, but if you don't have your settings.xml setup correctly, you won't be able to resolve the actual dependency.  And currently (as of July 1, 2015) there is a problem with pulling down the artifact.  The credentials sent aren't validating where they were previously.